# Pearson correlation (cor.test) using specific columns of a data matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to determine pair-wise pearson correlation coefficients and significance (p-value) between two sets of 6 columns each.

[image: Table]

I'm using the following script:

```
output <- matrix(dim(data2)[1]*4,dim(data2)[1],4)
for (i in dim(data)[1]){
    r<-cor.test(data[i,c(2:7)],data[i,c(9:14)],method="pearson")
    output[i,3]<-r$p.value
    output[i,4]<-r$estimate
    output[i,1]<-data[,1] # target geneID
    output[i,2]<-data[i,8] # miRNAID
}
colnames(output) <- c("geneID","miRNAID","p-val","corr")
head(output)
```

But I'm having issue with the type of vector in data matrix

[image]

I'd greatly appreciate your inputs regarding the issue.

Thanks
V

Comment: The error msg is quite explanatory - `cor.test` only works on vectors. You're sending data frames instead, so it doesn't work. Have a look at the [corrr package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/corrr/index.html) for handy ways to compute correlations

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you want to do this:

```
gene<-c("gene.17472635","gene.17436226","gene.17424189")
gene.C1<-c(216.22244180,0.04166939,29.58526377)
gene.C2<-c(210.4407513,0.6071574,24.684428)
gene.C3<-c(153.9317645,0.8830194,19.8798697)
gene.S1<-c(156.23494974,2.308891,23.345456)
gene.S2<-c(128.602680,4.568860,12.725349)
gene.S3<-c(52.928491,6.04392,7.174450)

data<-as.matrix(cbind(gene.C1,gene.C2,gene.C3,gene.S1,gene.S2,gene.S3))
cols<-t(combn(1:6,2))

gene_data_pval<-apply( cols , 1 , function(x) cor.test( data[,x[1]] , data[,x[2]],method="pearson")$p.value )
gene_data_estimate<-apply( cols , 1 , function(x) cor.test( data[,x[1]] , data[,x[2]],method="pearson")$estimate)
result1<-cbind(as.matrix(gene_data_pval),as.matrix(gene_data_estimate))
colnames(result1)<-c("p-val","est")
```

I am not sure if you want this or something else, thus only the gene data, but the code can be easily adopted for the mri one.

Remark: You can make a vector of ids according to the combinations.